# randomly assigning 1-1 relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to take a set of People and randomly assign them to a set of Locations. Obviously someone can only be 1 place at one time. I am doing this for sake of generating some test data for prototyping.

So, I have 10 people and 3 Locations (let's say). All 10 people need to be located at any of those 3 locations. I need it to be something like real life so they can't all be in one place. And everyone has to have only one place. Some uniform-ish distribution is what I am looking for.

```
match (p:Person), (l:Location) where not (p)-[:LOCATED]->(l) create (p)-[:LOCATED]->(l)
```

I am just not quite handy enough with Cypher and I don't want to have to resort to Java code for the job though I could do this easily

Comment: Do you want to do this through the web browser? Aside from Java, are there any other languages you'd consider using for this?

Comment: If I have to use anything other Cypher then I will just use Java

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to generate test data is using [Neode](https://github.com/iansrobinson/neode/). It provides a programmatic interface to easily generate a graph and allows you to choose between prebuilt strategies or implement your own. The best way to learn how it works is reading through the tests at https://github.com/iansrobinson/neode/tree/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/neode/test.